WebView2 pops up message box "localhost says" - html file
I use webview2 control to show html content located on a local folder structure. This works well, but.
I happens that a [OK] message box pops up with message title "localhost says" and html url file path.
For some html content it shows this message box, for other html content it doesn't
Also WebView2 may show this message box when doing refresh.
You can click OK button which then proceeds as it should.
Any information where this message box comes from?
WebView2 123.0.2420.81
No idea if same issue with other WebView2 versions
The basic apis
CreateCoreWebView2EnvironmentWithOptions
CreateCoreWebView2Controller
SetVirtualHostNameToFolderMapping  "localhost" - local folder with htm.
are used to show html content from files on the local system.
I would not expect a messagebox with message box "localhost says - ...."

If script running in a WebView2 calls alert, confirm, prompt, or uses the beforeunload event, the WebView2 control will show a corresponding window to the end user. This window will match what the Edge browser shows. For example, if web content in example.com runs alert('1'), you will get a window that contains the text 'example.com says 1'.
You can use the CoreWebView2.ScriptDialogOpening event to hide the default UI and show your own instead.
